# How do I find out how many items are in my world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would like to find out how many hoppers I have in the world. I've tried

```
/testforblock hopper
/testforblock minecraft:hopper
/testfor hopper
```

But I get an

```
Unknown command
```

Comment: Why the downvotes? It's a legitimate question.

Comment: We remove things like thanks, hi, and other greetings because they're not part of building a repository of knowledge.  Please don't roll them back.  Additionally, how legitimate a question is has no bearing on question utility; you could be having a specific problem, but if it's not useful to others (and you don't show effort for solving it yourself), it will get downvotes.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do something for the entire world, because to load it all, you would need many times the power of the biggest supercomputer in the word.
There is also no command to do something for all blocks in an area.

If you play in the world alone, you can look at your statistic for how many hoppers you have placed and subtract the number of hoppers you have broken, that should get you pretty close to the number. It does not include hoppers that were broken by explosions.

Comment: I want to remark that, to make the statement in the first sentence accurate, I actually looked up the fastest supercomputer and made a rough calculation for how much more power you would need. If I still remember it correctly, it was something between 10× and 100×.

Answer (score -2):

Do /testfor @e , it will list all items (and mobs)

Comment: He's not asking about drops.

Comment: Use an invsee Plugin for inventories, chests are not possible

Comment: Well, with plugins you can do everything. You could also probably convert NBT to text and search for "hopper" or something like that. But since you didn't even name the plugin, this is not a complete answer. Especially in the state it's in, `testfor @e` does something completely different.